# Installing Ubuntu Server LTS-18 on Virtual Machine

Tags: server

I want to know that there is two type of Installing Process is there

1) Installing using the Live Server Installer

2) Installation using debian-installer

what is difference between this given above both Installer ?

also what is Vanilla Ubuntu Server, MAAS bare-metal cloud rack controller or MAAS region controller ??

what is difference between this & which one to select ?

also I can find multiple videos of YouTube, but does Canonical or Ubuntu has own Videos on YouTube to see how to Install & how it works?

Waiting for your Valuable reply,

Comment: Virtual Machines are generally considered disposable. Experiment. Try both installers, and then you tell us the difference. (Hint: one installs Ubuntu, one installs Debian). Since you are using a VM, do not try to use MAAS. Or experiment with MAAS on a VM, and see what happens. There are actually many more VM install methods - most depend upon the VM host that you use (Vbox, VMWare, KVM, etc). Personally, I use Cloud Images on Qemu/KVM...but that's just personal taste.

Comment: Ok. I'll not try with MAAS on VMWare Workstation



also if I Install Ubuntu Server 18 LTS directly on a PC then which method to select ? Live Server Installation ?